# Is axios convert 0 to null in response?

Tags: javascript, axios, apisauce

Hello everyone i'm working with apisause(axios wrapper) and calling an api to get statistics, the results is numbers always but i have a special case when the result is 0 `axios somehow convert it into null`

here is the response from Preview Tap

[image]

and when i log the response from axios  this is what i get

[image]

Any clue Why this is happening ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does the response tab show the same thing, just with no formatting?

Comment: @Djave yes it's the same

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `Content-length: "1"` I would say, that's the answer from resource.
Could you try hitting API with Postman/Fiddler or Swagger UI?

Comment: I did on Swagger but it gives 0

`content-length: 1 
 content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
 date: Mon, 08 Feb 2021 12:02:24 GMT 
 server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 
 x-powered-by: ASP.NET`

Comment: If the Swagger responses with same response, then that's actual response from the server. The thing is that content-type is set to application/json, but the response contains "0" and it isn't valid JSON response, so the axios makes a transformation to null (0 = invalid json = null response). If server would response "{}" then the data would be an empty object.